# RDLC Text Box Expression Help Required !

Tags: asp.net, reporting, rdlc, formula

I have a table in my RDLC file. I want to change the text of its on column based on a value.
I tried something like this:

```
=iif(First(Fields!IsMemberOfHousehold.Value, "DSClientContact")=false,"Yes","No")
```

but this shows No in all rows of that column whereas I have a True and a False in DB. And it must show one Yes and one No.

The thing I want to do is when `First(Fields!IsMemberOfHousehold.Value, "DSClientContact")` returns True, I want to show "Yes" and if it returns False, I want to show "No".

Any help please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
=iif( CBool(First(Fields!IsMemberOfHousehold.Value, "DSClientContact"))=false , "Yes", "No" )
```